# JavaFX: MVC naming conventions

Tags: design-patterns, javafx, software-design

I am building a library and (I think I am ) following MVC.

- Model defines the specs/instructions.
- View interprets the instruction to create a visual that is added to the scene.
- Controller provides a GUI (Java controlsv ie. Sliders) through which the user changes the model.

So the library is organised as:
 Controller -> Model -> View

Wrt  naming conventions, should the class names reflect the functional role of the class in the library: for example, ShapeView, or should it reflect its actual class types (ShapeGroup)?

In this case, ShapeView interprets instructions from a ShapeModel class and creates shapes, then adds them to its children. The ShapeView/Group is then added to a Pane.

Currently I am going with roles for the naming convention for three reasons:
 - it is clearer to understand the role of the class from the name. 
 - class types are finite, so my naming convention would be limited if it were  to be tied to them.
 - I can rebuild the same library without being tied to names of classes of a certain programming language.

Is my intuition correct? I realize there are many ways to go about this, so I am seeking wisdom from experts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Model defines the specs/instructions.
>
> View interprets the instruction to create a visual that is added to
>   the scene.
>
> Controller provides a GUI (Java controlsv ie. Sliders) through which
>   the user changes the model.
>
> So the library is organised as: Controller -> Model -> View

You appear to be structuring your MVC pattern correctly. However I have always found the nuance of the MVC pattern to be a bit more... un-intuitive...  than other MV?? patterns. Because the concept of the 'view-controller' is generally included but not part of the MVC name, and 'how' the controller's UI/UX is "different" than the view's generally isn't as well defined as I'd like (because now a days the user is generally interacting interactively with data) And with MVC you have UI/UX 'output' within the 'view' and 'input' within the 'controller'.

[Wiki: Model–view–controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

---

Another design you might also want to consider is the MVP pattern. Model = data, View = passive UI, and Presenter handles the interaction between the two.

I find MVP easier to implement/think about(personally), since it has a non-cyclical nature (well... not really... since the flow of logic is still basically a loop, but the API boundaries of the Presenter is a cleaner boundary than 'View' in MVP) Which helps decouple V and M in MVP than is possible in MVC.

Also this allows you to independently change the Model or the View without the other one knowing. (technically MVC allows this, but it isn't as obvious/clear that you can do this, without the inclusion of the 'view-controller' between the model and the view.)

So for example you a DB of 'widgets' and the logic to access it as your model. and you have a View that can display them/get interactions from the user. If you define all the (one way) APIs (4 in total) as interfaces, then you can easily swap views (or have another team/dev) work on the UI/UX while you work on controller/model. (This is the biggest benefit I find, is having the UI code centrally located and not spread across 1/2 the 'view' and 1/2 the controller.

---

The one downside to MVP is that you can have a lot of calls 'passing through' the presenter with little to no changes before they hit the view. This can be a little confusing and harder to follow, but that is often when you push the code/logic more into the Model and View. (which might be appropriate), but having the presenter there allows you to treat it as as essentially just a  'bridge' object when needed, even if you aren't making use of it initially.

[Wiki: Model–view–presenter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter)

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I am new to patterns. I think my code might actually be an MVP now... Here is why: my controllers are basically passive shapes --for example circles which serve only the purpose of detecting mouse events. circles positions is bound to the model. Once a mouse event is detected, mouse-delta positions on scene are sent to the model to change its values. So in a sense, the controller is pretty much a passive view that receives input. The VIEW view (the shapes) are passive views too. their job is to process the model properties into shapes. I updated my question above.

Comment: No I think that is still MVC, its fine to use MVC, I just find MVP easier (for myself) and the decoupling I have found very useful (because I don't work on UI, so I make a 'it barely works UI' and then make the M and P rock solid and have someone else make a 'pretty' UI/View)